# Solana Anchor CPI call that requires pre-created account

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I am using Anchor for developing my Solana programs, and I'm wondering how should I make CPI calls that require previously created accounts, for instance, I wasn't able to find how to calculate rent-exemption amount. Should I init these accounts like this?

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateNft<'info> {
  #[account(init, payer = user, space = 967)]
  pub candy_machine: AccountInfo<'info>,
  #[account(mut)]
  pub user: Signer<'info>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, you've done this correctly! If the CPI requires previously created accounts, no need to calculate rent or anything -- it's already good to go. You can just declare it as `#[account]` or `#[account(mut)]` as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in the `AccountInfo` if it already exists (no need for `init`) but you do want constraints to check and make sure the account(s) passed in are correct and not some malicious account pretending to be the real thing. For some things like token accounts, Anchor has built in primitives for this.